# Reset functions after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I have this javascript file: http://pastebin.com/m2keHsTM

A big part of it is a toggle switch that works by sliding your finger or mouse on it. As you see at the end of the document

```
var togglebox = "<div class='toggle_box'></div>";
    $('input[type=checkbox]').css('display','none');
    $('fieldset[data-input-type=checkbox]').append(togglebox);
    var mouseDown = false;
    var beginTouchDown = 0;
    create_elements();
    set_listeners();
```

replaces the checkboxes on the page by div's that are "slideable" This works great, only when I load another page trough ajax, other new checkboxes do not get replaced. 
Is there a way to reset those functions and make them check again after an ajax call?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the original functions to `hijacklinks()` to initiate them each time the page changes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Call `set_listeners` also after the `load` function call: http://api.jquery.com/load
2. Change `set_listeners` to bind to events with `live` instead of `bind` or `mouse...` event binders: http://api.jquery.com/live

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean. I added the **also** word in my first option; that may explain it better.